# WANDB run initialization

Tags: python, wandb

I wanted to try using wandb to log runs of my ML experiments for a project; but I am not able to initialize the run itself.
I tried:

```
run = wandb.init(project="name",entity="username",name="classification")
```

This results in:

```
wandb: W&B API key is configured (use `wandb login --relogin` to force relogin)

wandb: Network error (ConnectTimeout), entering retry loop.

wandb: Network error (ConnectTimeout), entering retry loop.
```

What can I do to fix this? (I did login through the terminal before launching this cell idk what else to try)

Comment: hi, is this still an issue?

Comment: are you running W&B locally? if so, the notebook needs to send metrics over the network to the wandb server running on localhost:8080. This means the notebook must be running on the same machine as the local wandb server. If you ran wandb local on that machine it will be configured to talk to the server on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issues was resolved by using the following two commands -

```
wandb offline
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1
```